# Calclulating a set of lines slopes after using Xlim in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, signals

I'm plotting a series of lines in MATLAB and the figure is like this:

[image]

As you can see the X-axis is Frequency, I want to limit the frequency spectrum so I use Xlim function in my code to select my desired bandwidth while plotting.

Now I want to calculate the slope of those lines in the chosen frequency bandwidth (what's in the plot window), not the entire band but if I choose the basic fitting option, it's clearly giving me a linear fit for the line over the entire frequency band.

[image]

Any advice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the matlab script:

```
% your data
f = linspace(2e7,11e7,100);
x = linspace(-0.5,-2.5,100)+0.1*rand(1,100);
% Linear fit in a specific range:
[~,i] = find( f>3e7 & f<9e7 ); % <= set your range here
p = polyfit(f(i),x(i),1); % <= note the (i) for both variables

figure;
hold all
plot(f,x,'r.-')
plot(f(i),polyval(p,f(i)),'k-','LineWidth',2) % <= polyval takes the 'p' from polyfit + the data on the x-axis
% the fit is y = p(1)*x+p(2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to use the basic fitting GUI for what you want to do.  You will probably need to write a custom function that will "crop" the data in question to the x-limits of your current view.  Then use `polyfit` or similar on those data segments to create the fit.